# Want to check if an element is clickable in selenium without waiting for it

Tags: selenium

I have an element in a table. I want to check if the element is clickable or not.
I dont want to wait for it to be clickable. I just want to check if it is clickable.
Please help.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "clickable" The answer below is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

if it is enabled and visible to selenium then it should be clickable, shouldn't it be ?
Now if there is any pre condition i.e if you select `I agree` button then only you can click on `Okay button`. Those things are exception for this answer.

**isDisplayed() Method in Selenium**

The isDisplayed() method is used to check whether an element is displayed on a web page or not.

```
driver.findElement(By.locatorType(“path”)).isDisplayed();
```

**isEnabled() Method in Selenium**

isEnabled() method is used to check if the web element is enabled or disabled within the web page.

```
driver.findElement(By.locatorType(“path”)).isEnabled();
```

Comment: It is a date picker, which has only 30 days enabled. Rest are disabled. I want to check if the past dates are enabled or disabled.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a try/except like this

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
driver.implicitly_wait(0)

try:
   element.click()
except ElementNotInteractableException:
   # TODO: put something here
```